# In review, is my vote reversed if I vote, then hit Skip?

Tags: discussion, review-queues

I often find myself upvoting comments, leaving comments of my own, and voting on questions in queues. Occasionally, after doing this, I'm a position where none of the review options are good.

When I hit skip, do the decisions I've made with the post persist? Why am I allowed to skip after making decisions? I'm specifically referring to voting, commenting, and flagging, particularly in First Posts and Late Answers.

Comment: are you talking about voting for close or upvote / downvote ?

Comment: Late Answers and First Posts are the queues I frequent. I'm referring to voting.

Comment: IIRC any actions take effect as soon as you do them.  So regardless of your final review verdict (Skip, Done) votes and comments have already been registered.  You can of course test this yourself.

Comment: That's what I was able to find with my own testing- I knew votes persisted, wasn't sure about things like flags. That seems odd to me.

Comment: This would be easy enough to test for yourself. Just vote up a post like you normally would, hit skip, then go see that post to see if your vote is still there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> When I hit skip, do the decisions I've made with the post persist?

Yes.  No button that you press in any review queue ever reverse *any* action that you've performed before hitting the button.

> Why am I allowed to skip after making decisions?

Why shouldn't you be able to?  I wouldn't expect it to be common, but there may certainly be cases where you see something that you can do without being able to do the thing that the review queue actually sent you there for.  This would certainly be less common for first posts and late answers (that are more broad and ambiguous in the problems they're asking you to fix) than it would be in more focused queues that are asking a rather specific question (say, is this edit appropriate, which you might not know the answer to even if you see something about the post worth commenting on).

Comment: You can't comment on posts from within Suggested Edits. You *can*, however, comment, and upvote comments, from within Close or Reopen.